# How to create a simple split page layout

Tags: adobe-indesign, book

I am new to InDesign and I am trying to create a file to get an image book published.

For page 1, I want to split the page into 2 halves, where 1 half has text and the other is filled with an image. I managed to do this manually (create a panel and then copy + paste and adjust the size until the 2 panels are of equal size and fill the page), but figured there  must be an easier way.

So I turned on the "snap to grid" feature in the hopes that the grid would pass through the center of the page, but this doesn't seem to be the case..

So my question is, how can I move the baseline grid so that it aligns to the center of my book, **OR** how can I define a page layout to contain 2 half-page panels?

Here is what I mean by the grid is not aligning:

[image]

Black line is the midde of the book (inner spine), and the purple lines are the margins. As you can see the grid is slightly off, meaning that when "snap-to-grid" is turned on, I am unable to easily find the center of the page.

Is it supposed to be like that? Am I using the wrong grid feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust your grid under prefrences > grid

There are several ways to control placement. Instead of the grid I prefer to use guides and master pages (if you are new to InDesign, I recommend reading about the power of master pages). Either way, to get two vertical halves, I would recommend setting up columns. Select the pages or master pages you want to apply this to, then go to Layout > Margin and columns. From there, set the desired columns and gutters. For horizontal halves I would use guides, click and drag on the ruler to make guides, and drop them on the page (or the master to apply to several pages), you can select guides and adjust the placement as you like.